# How can program a variable in my android application that causes appearance of a notification for each 10 minutes

Tags: java, android

hi i am new in android and i should doing this projet,please can you help me?

this is my question:
How can program a variable in my android application that causes appearance of a notification for each 10 minutes, and after 2 hour it should stop?

i already search in google and found this code, i am not sure is this code can help me or not?

please can you tell me if it is doing the same that my question ?

```
public class AlarmDemoActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener { 
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
private PendingIntent mAlarmIntent;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    findViewById(R.id.start).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.stop).setOnClickListener(this);
    Intent launchIntent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    mAlarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, launchIntent, 0);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    long interval = 5*1000; //5 seconds

    switch(v.getId()) {
    case R.id.start:
        Toast.makeText(this, "Scheduled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,
                SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()+interval,
                interval,
                mAlarmIntent);
        break;
    case R.id.stop:
        Toast.makeText(this, "Canceled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        manager.cancel(mAlarmIntent);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}

private long nextStartTime() {
    long oneDay = 24*3600*1000; //24 hours
    //Set the time to 09:00:00
    Calendar startTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    startTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 9);
    startTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    startTime.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
    if(now.before(startTime)) {
        return startTime.getTimeInMillis();
    } else {
        startTime.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        return startTime.getTimeInMillis();
    }
}
}
```

the AlarmReciver class

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
    DateFormat formatter = SimpleDateFormat.getTimeInstance();
    Toast.makeText(context, formatter.format(now.getTime()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

This is XML:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <Button
android:id="@+id/start"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="Start Alarm"
 />
 <Button
android:id="@+id/stop"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="Cancel Alarm"
 />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: That code would set a timer to 9:00 and show a Notification then. It works by telling the Alarm Service to broadcast `mAlarmIntent` at the given time and `AlarmReceiver` catches that one and shows a Notification. If you request multiple alarms for the next 2 hours, 10 minutes each it would do what you want.

Comment: @zapl you mean this code is suitable for me? because i will take a variable time as string i mean like "12:30" then i want to notify the user for each 10 minutes until 2 hours, so is it suitable to me?

Comment: you need to adjust the code a bit but yes, it should fit your needs pretty good.

Comment: can you tell me what is should i adjust by updating my code,please?

Comment: I don't have the time to write it for you but you would have to change `manager.setRepeating` so that it has a 10 minute interval (time expected in miliseconds) and also include the stop time in the Intent (e.g. via `Intent.putExtra(String name, long value)`) so the Receiver knows when the Alarm should end and call `AlarmManager.cancel()`